# Lua code to recognize texlua versus luatex

Tags: luatex

I have some `foo.lua` code that needs to behave slightly differently when loaded from luatex or texlua.
Here is my example document.

```
%!TeX Program=LuaLaTeX
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{luacode}
\begin{document}
\begin{luacode}
require("foo.lua")
\end{luacode}
\end{document}
```

and here is `foo.lua`

```
if is_luatex then
  tex.sprint("Hello LuaTeX World!")
else
  print("Hello TeXLua World!")
end
```

How to define `is_luatex`?
My first idea is to parse `arg[0]` but I really need a very strong solution that covers the widest range of situations (99.999%).

Answer (score 2):

You can just test for the function you are using

```
if tex.sprint then
  tex.sprint("Hello LuaTeX World!")
else
  print("Hello TeXLua World!")
end
```

luatex typesets

[image]

texlua does

```
$ texlua foo.lua 
Hello TeXLua World!
```

If you first tested for the tex table, you could also detect stock Lua rather than texlua

Comment: Is it documented?

Comment: @JérômeLAURENS I'm not sure what you mean? The construct is just basic Lua, the fact that texlua doesn't supply the tex related features in the `tex` table is sort of hinted at in the luatex manual but (like many things) could perhaps be more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

There is no documented straightforward flag to make the difference between LuaTeX and TeXLua, but we can take advantage of the fact that LuaTeX defines command sequences whereas TeXLua does not. The number of command sequences defined is available through `status.cs_count`:

```
local is_luatex = status.cs_count > 0
if is_luatex then
  tex.sprint("Hello LuaTeX World!")
else
  print("Hello TeXLua World!")
end
```

Comment: David's solution is stronger than yours, IMO. Unless you restrict yourself to LuaLaTeX, it won't work properly

Comment: @Jairo Could you be more explicit?

Comment: Nowadays there are LuaTeX (and variations of it) and LuaMetaTeX, the latter currently only used by ConTeXt. While the `tex` library is defined for both of them (and then the `tex.print` check works fine), `status.cs_count` will trigger an error message in latest ConTeXt. Again, if you're only interested in LuaLaTeX, your test is fine, but David's one is really as generic as possible.